# AWS application load balancer on unknown dynamic url paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible to do url path load balancing on an AWS application load balancer when the paths are generated dynamically? 
e.g

example.com/abc12345
example.com/abc54321

Please note there is no structure to how the urls are formed

I've got a scenario where "rooms" will be generated dynamically and I want to be able to load balance them. The names of the rooms won't be known upfront and the other issue is that an external service will ping them (hence why I need to load balance on the url rather than a cookie/session).

Does anyone know if this is able to be accomplished, or is there a better way to achieve this. I'm not familiar enough with load balancing methods. My initial thoughts would be very simple in that I hash the PATH and then retrieve an integer value from it (Via modulus or equivalent) and load balance based on that.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

I'm specifically looking at AWS in this instance due to the location of other resources, but if this could be achieved via something like NGINX and spinning up my own Load Balancer I'd be all ears.

Comment: The code to be runned will be different depending on the room number?

Comment: I guess it would be good to have some kind of dictionary. So paths that start 'abc' go to one server, paths that begin 'xyz' go to another. The only caveat there is I can't ensure even load distribution. And for a given url it should return the same server

Comment: I don't think what you want is a load balancer. You see, load balancer is to distribute the load between identical instances, to make sure all requests can be dealt with. If you need to adopt different logic depending on what is after the `/ `, maybe what is need is `nginx`. With and ngninx routing your requests, you can forward they to the proper instance/load balancer.

Comment: I get that and in theory each instance should be able to handle any request. So ideally a new room would be load balanced and then any subsequent requests to the same url would go to the same server that that room was initially sent to based on the traffic at the time.

Comment: You can achieve that by enabling `sticky sessions` on your load balancer. This way, a user will always be routed to the same instance, unless the instance dies or their IP changes.

Comment: As I said in my initial question I have enough service that will need to hit the url so sessions are a no go as there won’t be one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy a Cloudfront distribution in front of your application. with CF, you can route different path by prefix to different load balancers. (/abc* to LB1 and /xyz* to LB2) You can even route some paths to non–AWS endpoints or S3 buckets.

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

With Cloudfront you also access to other features such as caching specific paths and it will also accelerate your application globally comparing to having Load Balancers in one region.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the issue is I still can't really "load balance" my solution unless I implement some kind of round robin when the random room names are created to evenly distribute the traffic